# How to find label which has the "for" property pointing to current DIV or textarea

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom-events

I have two elements, one textarea, and one div, with a label attached to each of them (using the "for").
HTML::

```
<textarea  id="txta_1" class="txta" cols="40" rows="3" onkeyup="charCount(this)" ></textarea><br>
<label id="label_1" for="txta_1"></label>

<div id="DIV_1" class="DIV_" contenteditable onkeyup="charCount(this)" >hello</div>
<label id="label_2" for="DIV_1"></label>
```

the Javascript is:

```
function charCount(th)
{  ("Label element which is attached to it using the FOR").innerHTML = th.value.length; 
}
```

How do I grab the element which has the correct "for" property for the respective element?
Thank you and much appreciated

Comment: `labels` can't be applied to `div` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an HTML label is referenced by a "for" attribute on another element, it has a property `element.labels` that contains a list of referencing label elements.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/labels

```
<label id="label1" for="test">Label 1</label>
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<label id="label2" for="test">Label 2</label>

const select = document.getElementById("test");
for(var i = 0; i < select.labels.length; i++) {
  console.log(select.labels[i].textContent); // "Label 1" and "Label 2"
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks @C14L, I guess then I just have to substitute the "element" in select.element. with stuff like "Input" or something.. e.g. if my main "test" element is a form? I have some of those as well